# Remove duplicate data from an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array of data

```
data = [20001202.05, 20001202.05, 20001202.50, 20001215.75, 20021215.75]
```

I remove the duplicate data with `list(set(data))`, which gives me

```
data = [20001202.05, 20001202.50, 20001215.75, 20021215.75]
```

But I would like to remove the duplicate data, based on the numbers before the "period"; for instance, if there is `20001202.05` and `20001202.50`, I want to keep one of them in my array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you don't care about the order of the items you keep, you could do:

```
>>> {int(d):d for d in data}.values()
[20001202.5, 20021215.75, 20001215.75]
```

---

If you would like to keep the *lowest* item, I can't think of a one-liner.

Here is a basic example for anybody who would like to add a condition on the key or value to keep.

```
seen = set()
result = []
for item in sorted(data):
    key = int(item)  # or whatever condition
    if key not in seen:
        result.append(item)
        seen.add(key)
```

Comment: In your updated answer, there's no reason to use `sorted(data)`.

Comment: A `set` is effectively just a `dict` with keys but no values - both use a hash table internally

Comment: @martineau < There is, if you want to keep only the lowest item, for example in `data = [1.75, 1.05]`.

Comment: You can do the latter in two lines, but it's awkward and not very pythonic - `seen = set(); result = [item for item in data if int(item) not in seen and seen.add(int(item)) is None]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe < thank you for pointing out that `set()` is built on an optimized version of the hashing algorithm used for dict. Your two liner is nice too, even if I dislike repeating type conversion :^)

Comment: Well, the OP never mentioned a desire to keep only the lowest item, just that "...I want to keep one of them". I felt is was important to point out because doing an unnecessary sort operation could have a significant impact on performance.

Answer (score 4):

Generically, with python 3.7+, because dictionaries maintain order, you can do this, even when order matters:

```
data = {d:None for d in data}.keys()
```

---

However for OP's original problem, OP wants to de-dup based on the integer value, not the raw number, so see the top voted answer. But generically, this will work to remove true duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
data1 = [20001202.05, 20001202.05, 20001202.50, 20001215.75, 20021215.75]
for i in data1:
   if i not in ls:
      ls.append(i)
print ls
```

Comment: You forgot to declare the variable `ls` and this still doesn't solve completely the problem, as it doesn't account the second condition of the OP.

Comment: Yes i apologize for this